# Ajaxmin MinifyJavascript adding {} before object

Tags: javascript, microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

I am facing an issue while minifying a [javascript file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xsoh/moment-hijri/master/moment-hijri.js) using AjaxMin's MinifyJavaScript method.

Unminified Code

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['moment'], function (moment) {
            root.moment = factory(moment)
            return root.moment
        })
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('moment'))
    } else {
        root.moment = factory(root.moment)
    }
```

Minified Code

```
if(typeof define=="function"&&define.amd)define(["moment"],function(i){return n.moment=t(i),n.moment});else if(typeof exports=="object"){module{}.exports=t(require("moment"))}else n.moment=t(n.moment)}
```

Here in minified code "{}" is added after module object e.g.: module{}.exports but it should be module.exports

There are few more files before minifying the file:
1. jquery-3.3.1.min.js
2. moment.min.js

All the files are bundled in single file and after that minification is done.

Comment: `C#` tag looks like a misplaced tag here...

Comment: You need to put some `;` in your code. The carriage returns are signifying the end of your lines, once you remove these and without any `;` your minified code does something very different.

Comment: I tried with ; also but it gives me same result

Comment: so what's your minified output now? Please edit the question.

Comment: The one mentioned above

Comment: what is `module` where do you define it? Does the rest of your code have the correct `;`?

Comment: It gives you the same result? Even though you've added `;`. That obviously can't be true because it would at a minimum add the `;`....

Comment: Yes, it gives me the same result just along with ;. The "{}" is still added which gives me the runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this are the causes to the problem

1. **ajaxmin** [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ajaxmin/blob/master/AjaxMin/AjaxMin.resx) module seems to be a reserved word
2. If/else scopes doesn't compiles properly to the output.

This seems to causing the issue

```
var blockType = AjaxMin.BlockTypeModule.FormatInvariant
(moduleScope.ScopeName.IfNullOrWhiteSpace(AjaxMin.ModuleNameImplicit));
```

Workaround (this is what I did in my project):

- You can replace that string `module{}.` with `module.`
- use ternary operator instead of if/else (most probably this will skip the replacement of that whole chunk)
- use minify version of that file (this will skip the minify)